# Average square Euler's formula for trigonometric identities

Tags: waves, diffraction

We know that the average value for a squared cossine on a full period is:
$$\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\cos^2(\omega t)dt=\frac{1}{2}$$
And the same value holds for a sine. But if we use Euler's formula, then:
$$\int_0^Te^{2i(\omega t)}dt=\int_0^T(\cos^2(\omega t)-\sin^2(\omega t)+i\cos(\omega t)\sin(\omega t))dt=0$$

This doesn't seem that is correct but why? I encountered this problem when trying to find the intensity of a difraction pattern of a difracted wave, where :
$$I\space \alpha \space \langle \Psi^2(x,t)|_{x=0} \rangle$$

Where $\Psi(x,t)=Ae^{i(\omega t-kx+\phi)}\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sin(\phi/2)}$ is the wave function and $\phi$ a constant. I was expecting that the average value of it would be 1, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you say this is not correct?

Comment: Because if the the average is really 0 then the intensity is 0 and we get no difraction pattern and we know that there is in fact a difraction pattern. Plus, I used complex notation just because the sum operation of several waves would be much easier, but I could easily have made it representing the wave as a function of just sine or cossine and add a phase and I would get to the same result except the average value over a period

Comment: You have to take the $|\Psi|^2$, not the $\Psi^2$.

Comment: Why? That would definitely solve my problem because $|e^{ix}|$=1

Comment: PS. In math notation use `\sin` instead of `sin`. This renders with upright characters as it should for functions. See $\sin(x)$ vs. $sin(x)$. The same with `\cos` and `\tan` etc.